# What is the difference between Subject and BehaviorSubject?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, behaviorsubject, subject

I'm not clear on the difference between a `Subject` and a `BehaviorSubject`. Is it just that a `BehaviorSubject` has the `getValue()` function?

Comment: nice answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55991072/7186739

Comment: @dev I agree...

Answer (score 570, accepted):

A BehaviorSubject holds one value. When it is subscribed it emits the value immediately. A Subject doesn't hold a value.

Subject example (with RxJS 5 API):

```
const subject = new Rx.Subject();
subject.next(1);
subject.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Console output will be empty

BehaviorSubject example:

```
const subject = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(0);
subject.next(1);
subject.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Console output: 1

In addition:

- `BehaviorSubject` should be created with an initial value: new `Rx.BehaviorSubject(1)`
- Consider `ReplaySubject` if you want the subject to get previously published values.

Comment: So do you mean you have to subscribe to subject before subject.next() to for this to work?

Comment: @eric for Subject, yes. That is the distinction.

Comment: Note that you have to pass in the first value to BehaviorSubject's constructor ;)

Comment: if we create  subject with boolean even subject emits rite?? 

  const subject = new Subject<boolean>();
  subject.next(true);

Comment: If it helps: Subjects = Event - BehaviorSubject = State;

Comment: When you say "A Subject doesn't hold a value" it's kind of confusing. If you show one more example for "Subject" where you subscribe first and _then_ call `.next(1)`, it will make your answer a lot more clear.

Comment: Often, we do not have the initial value, since we would like to [convert an observable to behavior subject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58199823/5770014): don't worry about the initial value, just use some 'empty' value.

Comment: I think the answer below has a better example. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59784108/12097072

Answer (score 361):

### BehaviourSubject

**BehaviourSubject will return the initial value or the current value on Subscription**

```
var bSubject= new Rx.BehaviorSubject(0);  // 0 is the initial value

bSubject.subscribe({
  next: (v) => console.log('observerA: ' + v)  // output initial value, then new values on `next` triggers
});

bSubject.next(1);  // output new value 1 for 'observer A'
bSubject.next(2);  // output new value 2 for 'observer A', current value 2 for 'Observer B' on subscription

bSubject.subscribe({
  next: (v) => console.log('observerB: ' + v)  // output current value 2, then new values on `next` triggers
});

bSubject.next(3);
```

With output:

```
observerA: 0
observerA: 1
observerA: 2
observerB: 2
observerA: 3
observerB: 3
```

### Subject

**Subject does not return the current value on Subscription. It triggers only on `.next(value)` call and return/output the `value`**

```
var subject = new Rx.Subject();

subject.next(1); //Subjects will not output this value

subject.subscribe({
  next: (v) => console.log('observerA: ' + v)
});
subject.subscribe({
  next: (v) => console.log('observerB: ' + v)
});

subject.next(2);
subject.next(3);
```

With the following output on the console:

```
observerA: 2
observerB: 2
observerA: 3
observerB: 3
```

Comment: Its also more correct : "BehaviourSubject will return the initial value or the current value on Subscription" is a better explanation than "A BehaviorSubject holds one value."

Comment: I put the code above on Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-subjectvsbehaviorsubject

Comment: Where is observerB: 3?

Comment: @OPV ObserverB: 3 is there while you call `subject.next(3);`

Comment: So, what is the benefits of using one over the other? Any examples?

Comment: Useful for caching data, if you have a search page, then you nav to the details page then back to search. The search results can be stored in the obsv and used again.

Answer (score 204):

I just **created a project** which explain what is the **difference between all subjects**:
https://github.com/piecioshka/rxjs-subject-vs-behavior-vs-replay-vs-async

[image]

Comment: The documentation should be as simple as that, thank you!

Answer (score 32):

A `BehaviorSubject` holds one value (so we actually need to initialize a default value). When it is subscribed it emits that value **immediately**. A `Subject` on the other hand, does not hold a value.

What it actually means is that in `Subject`, the subscribers will **only receive the upcoming value** where as in `BehaviorSubject` the subscribers will **receive the previous value and also upcoming value**.

So, let's take an example to see how this will behave:

```
let mySubject = new Subject<number>();

mySubject.subscribe(x => console.log("The first Subscription : " + x));

mySubject.next(1);
mySubject.next(2);

mySubject.subscribe(x => console.log("The second Subscription : " + x));

mySubject.next(3);

// The first Subscription : 1
// The first Subscription : 2
// The first Subscription : 3
// The second Subscription : 3
```

Like we saw above, the first 2 values were output from the subject before the second subscription registered, so it didn't get them, it only got the new values after subscribed. The first subscription got them all, since it subscribed before the first values were output.

Now, let's change the `subject` to `BehaviorSubject` and see the difference:

```
let mySubject = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);

mySubject.subscribe((x) => console.log('The first Subscription : ' + x));

mySubject.next(1);
mySubject.next(2);

mySubject.subscribe((x) => console.log('The second Subscription : ' + x));

mySubject.next(3);

// The first Subscription : 0 (since it's the initial value)
// The first Subscription : 1
// The first Subscription : 2
// The second Subscription : 2 (since it's the initial value for the seconde subscriber)
// The first Subscription : 3
// The second Subscription : 3
```

Now, notice how the first subscriber outputs `0` since the `BehaviorSubject` was initialized with `0`. When the second subscriber subscribes, it immediately emits the '2' value since it was the last value to be handled so it acts as the initial value for it.

More about the difference between `BehaviorSubject` and `Subject` can be found [here](https://dev.to/revanth_oleti/difference-between-subject-and-behaviorsubject-9g6)

Comment: @Rad thank you for you explanation -> it really made sense to me 

Answer (score 27):

`BehaviorSubject` keeps in memory the last value that was emitted by the observable. A regular `Subject` doesn't.

`BehaviorSubject` is like `ReplaySubject` with a buffer size of 1.

UPDATE: There are edge use cases that distinguish those two. https://medium.com/javascript-everyday/behaviorsubject-vs-replaysubject-1-beware-of-edge-cases-b361153d9ccf

TLDR:
If you want to provide an initial value at subscription time, even if nothing has been pushed to a Subject so far, use the BehaviorSubject. If you want to have the last value replayed to an observer, even if a Subject is already closed, use the ReplaySubject(1).

Answer (score 18):

It might help you to understand.

```
import * as Rx from 'rxjs';

const subject1 = new Rx.Subject();
subject1.next(1);
subject1.subscribe(x => console.log(x)); // will print nothing -> because we subscribed after the emission and it does not hold the value.

const subject2 = new Rx.Subject();
subject2.subscribe(x => console.log(x)); // print 1 -> because the emission happend after the subscription.
subject2.next(1);

const behavSubject1 = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(1);
behavSubject1.next(2);
behavSubject1.subscribe(x => console.log(x)); // print 2 -> because it holds the value.

const behavSubject2 = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(1);
behavSubject2.subscribe(x => console.log('val:', x)); // print 1 -> default value
behavSubject2.next(2) // just because of next emission will print 2
```

Answer (score 2):

All three are quite different, let me give few more samples here,

```
const subject = new Rx.Subject();
const behaviorSubject = new Rx.BehaviorSubject([]);
const relaySubject = new Rx.ReplaySubject();


subject.next(1)

behaviorSubject.next(1); 
behaviorSubject.next(2); 
behaviorSubject.next(3);

relaySubject.next(1); 
relaySubject.next(2); 
relaySubject.next(3);

subject.subscribe(val => console.log('From Subject', val)); // this will not emits
behaviorSubject.subscribe(val => console.log('From BehaviorSubject', val)); // this will emits only last value
relaySubject.subscribe(val => console.log('From ReplaySubject', val)); // this will emit all values
```

[Output screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dLAT.png)

As you can see, when we subscribe to the subject after we emit(i.e next(...)),

1. subject - this will not get fired at all
2. behaviorSubject - this will fire once with last value
3. ReplaySubject - this will fire 3 time, as many `next()` we have

So the difference is mainly where you subscribe, whether it's before `next()` or after `next()`.

In practical case, we fire event's only after `next()` [i.e after we fill data to the subjects].

Answer (score 1):

A ***BehaviorSubject*** emits a value after subscription, a ***Subject*** no.

```js
// Subject
const mySubject = new Rx.Subject().subscribe((v) => console.log(v)); // will return nothing

// BehaviorSubject
const myBehaviorSubject = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(666).subscribe((v) => console.log(v)); // will return 666 when subscription occurs
```

Answer (score 1):

```
BehaviorSubject keeps in memory the last value that was emitted by the observable. A regular Subject doesn't. So we can update dynamic titles based on Behaviour Subject.


var bSubject= new Rx.BehaviorSubject(0);  // 0 is the initial value
    
    bSubject.subscribe({
      next: (v) => console.log('observerA: ' + v)  // output initial value, then new values on `next` triggers
    });
    
    bSubject.next(1);  // output new value 1 for 'observer A'
    bSubject.next(2);  // output new value 2 for 'observer A', current value 2 for 'Observer B' on subscription
    
    bSubject.subscribe({
      next: (v) => console.log('observerB: ' + v)  // output current value 2, then new values on `next` triggers
    });
    
    bSubject.next(3);
    
     - With Output
```

Answer (score 1):

Program to test all 4 Subjects types:
**Subject, BehaviorSubject, ReplaySubject and AsyncSubject**

```
// 1. Subject - only value after subscribed
var subject = new Subject();
subject.next(1);
subject.next(2);
subject.complete();
subject.subscribe(
  (data) => this.log("Subject="+data),
  (error) => this.log(error),
  () => this.log('Complete Subject')
);
subject.next(3);
subject.next(4);

// 2. BehaviorSubject - only last value before subscribed and all after subscription
// calls on initalization, mandatory to specify a value
var subjectb = new BehaviorSubject<any>(5);
subjectb.next(1);
subjectb.next(2);
subjectb.complete();
subjectb.subscribe(
  (data) => this.log("Behavior="+data),
  (error) => this.log(error),
  () => this.log('Complete Behavior')
);

// 3. ReplaySubject - all specified last values before subscribed and all after subscription
// Does not call on initalization, no default value
var subjectr = new ReplaySubject(5);
subjectr.next(1);
subjectr.next(2);
subjectr.complete();
subjectr.subscribe(
  (data) => this.log("Replay="+data),
  (error) => this.log(error),
  () => this.log('Complete Replay')
);

// 4. AsyncSubject - only last values before calling complete
var subjecta = new AsyncSubject();
subjecta.next(1);
subjecta.next(2);
subjecta.complete();
subjecta.subscribe(
  (data) => this.log("Async="+data),
  (error) => this.log(error),
  () => this.log('Complete Async')
);
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/example-rxjs-subject-e8vj9y?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts