# Angular 4 Observable returning undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services

First things first, this isn't related to some http request, it's way much simpler scenario where a components sets a boolean value and another component display/hide element based on it.

The problem is that the other component always receives 'undefined' in the subscribe call back. However, I tried to make the main component subscribe as well, and it's receiving the value correctly.

Here's my code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class EnablerService {
  private _enabled= new Subject<boolean>();
  get Enabled() { return this._enabled.asObservable(); }
  SetEnabled(value: boolean) {
    this._enabled.next(value);
    console.log(`service: ${value}`);
  }
}
```

main component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {EnablerService} from './enabler.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [EnablerService]
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  private _isEnabled: boolean;
  constructor(public service: EnablerService) {
    service.Enabled.subscribe(val => {
         this._isEnabled = val; 
         console.log(`app comp: ${this._isEnabled}`); 
    });
  }

  Switch() {
    this.service.SetEnabled(!this._isEnabled);
    console.log('switched');
  }
}
```

other component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {EnablerService} from './enabler.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-footer',
  templateUrl: './footer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./footer.component.css'],
  providers: [EnablerService]
})
export class FooterComponent implements OnInit {
  private _isEnabled: boolean;
  constructor(private service: EnablerService) {
    this._isEnabled = true;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.Enabled.subscribe(val => {
      this._isEnabled = val; // this one here.
      console.log(`footer comp: ${this._isEnabled}`);
    });
  }

}
```

The main component binds `Switch` method to a button, and it works. The console outputs this on click:

> app comp: true
>
> service: true
>
> switched
>
> undefined

clicking again will switch the `true` values to `false` but still gives undefined.

Anyone has an idea what's going on here??

Comment: I don't understand why `app comp: true` can be true. Something that could help you, would be to initialize your subject at start : `private _enabled= new Subject<boolean>(false);`

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe the Subject doesn't have constructor with parameter.

Comment: Thank you, as seen here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348463/what-is-the-difference-between-subject-and-behaviorsubject
I was wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you put your `EnablerService` in component's `providers` array, it would receive new instance of the service, while you need to share one between your components. You should provide `EnablerService` in some parent component only (maybe AppRoot component) and use it (inject it) in child components.

See [docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service) for a sample usage: only `MissionControlComponent` has `MissionService` listed in `providers`, `AstronautComponent` does not - it has it just injected.

Comment: It works now, thanks for the answer, didn't notice that I only needed to register it as provider once only.

Comment: I had the same issue once :) The idea is shortly described here: https://angular.io/guide/architecture#dependency-injection.

Comment: shouldn't we only inject the service in providers app.module , and no need to inject it again as provider in every components