# Passing object from one class to another undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I have a component which displays a list of objects. When one of the elements in this list is clicked, I would like to to pass the object to another component that is on another page.

So basically list component -> service component -> details component -> display the clicked list component details

List Component:

```
setCurrentMovie(movie: IMovie){
    this._currentMovieService.setCurrentMovie(movie);
  }
```

Service class which I am using to track the current object

```
  setCurrentMovie(movie: IMovie){
    this.movie = movie;
  }
  getCurrentMovie(): Observable<IMovie>{
    return of(this.movie);
  }
```

Details Component which displays the current object

```
getCurrentMovie(){
 console.log(this._currentMovieService.getCurrentMovie().subscribe(value=>this.currentMovie = value)); // logs undefined
}
```

Details component html

```
<div *ngIf="currentMovie">
  {{currentMovie.MovieName}}
</div>
```

This however doesn't display anything.

Comment: Where have you provided your service. In which module?
Try to move the service to a upper level

Comment: Are you sure your object has a `MovieName` property? Does `{{ currentMovie | json}}` display anything?

Comment: What's your `rxjs` version?

Comment: where are you invoking `getCurrentMovie()` method?

Comment: It's invoked in the ngOnInit of details component

Comment: @sander can you `console.log(value)` inside the subscribe of your details component?

Comment: @bugs it gives me null when I do that.

Comment: Share more code so I can help you out or provide a stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

`ngOnInit` is executed when your component is initialized and your `getCurrentMovie()` would for sure return `undefined` because the value is not set yet. Later when you are setting the value your `getCurrentMovie` method is not invoked either you force invoke it or go for `Behavior Subject`

I would suggest you go for  RxJS **[BehaviorSubject](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#behaviorsubject)**

You can also use a regular RxJS **[Subject](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#subject)**  service, but here’s some advantages of it over `subject`.

1. It will always return the current value on subscription - there is no need to call `onnext().`
2. It has a getValue() function to extract the last value as raw data.
3. It ensures that the component always receives the most recent data.
4. you can get an observable from behavior subject using the `asobservable()` 
        method on behavior subject.
5. **[Refer this for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348463/what-is-the-difference-between-subject-and-behaviorsubject)**

your **service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Imovie} from './imovie'
import {Observable,of,BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';
@Injectable()
export class ShareDataService {

private Movie= new BehaviorSubject<Imovie>(null);
  currentMovie = this.Movie.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

setCurrentMovie(movie:Imovie)
{
  this.Movie.next(movie);
}
}
```

**Component-1**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {ShareDataService} from './share-data.service'
import {Imovie} from './imovie'
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<div *ngIf="currentMovie">
  <h2>{{currentMovie.name}}</h2>
   <h2>{{currentMovie.genre}}</h2>
</div>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`] 
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  public currentMovie:Imovie;
 constructor(public service:ShareDataService)
 {
   this.service.currentMovie.subscribe((value)=>{this.currentMovie=value
     console.log(this.currentMovie);
   });
 }

}
```

**Component-2**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {ShareDataService} from './share-data.service'
import {Imovie} from './imovie';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  public movie:Imovie
  constructor(public service:ShareDataService)
  {

  }
setMovie()
{
this.movie={name:'grudge',genre:'horror'};
this.service.setCurrentMovie(this.movie);
}
}
```

**Component-2 HTML**

```
<button (click)="setMovie()" >SetMovie</button>
<hello></hello>
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yfanxr)**

Comment: I get an error in Component1 saying ""Cannot read property 'currentMovie' of undefined"

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz ?

Comment: The stackBlitz provided by you  misses lots of files kindly include those files