# Can't detect first Observable changing / view does not refresh

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, combinelatest

I have a little problem with subscribing my Observable

I have one one combined Observable:

```
private selectedEntryId$ = new Subject<number>();
private entries$ = new Subject<MappingEntry[]>();

private selectedEntry$ = Observable.combineLatest(
    this.entries$,
    this.selectedEntryId$,
    (entries: MappingEntry[], id: number) => {
        return entries.find((entry: MappingEntry) => {
            return entry.id === id;
        });
    });
```

I try do API call every time, when my `selectedEntry$` has next value and subscribe result in this way:

```
constructor(private checkService: CheckService) {
    this.subscribeLengthCalculator();
}

subscribeLengthCalculator() {
    this.subscriptions.add(
        this.selectedEntry$
            .switchMap((entry) => {
                return entry ? this.checkService.calculateLinesLength([entry.value]) : Observable.empty();
            }).subscribe(([calculation: CalculationObject]) => {
                    console.log(calculation);
                    this.calculation = calculation;
             })
    );
}
```

First time when `selectedEntry$` has next value, `console.log` throw to the console correct API result, but in my html `calculation` has null value. When `selectedEntry$` has second next value, `console.log` throw to the console correct API result too but in html show mi previous value. Anyone can explain me this behaviour and tell me what I should do to showing current data in html? It's very strange behaviour.

Comment: use `Behavior Subject` see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348463/what-is-the-difference-between-subject-and-behaviorsubject)

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [learnrxjs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) "Be careful though, you probably want to avoid `switchMap` in scenarios where every request needs to complete".

"The main difference between `switchMap` and other flattening operators is the cancelling effect", that is why when `selectedEntry$` has second next value, it show your previous value. The source observable (`this.selectedEntry$`) a;ready complete, the subscription is just active for the `Observable` coming from this line:

```
return entry ? this.checkService.calculateLinesLength([entry.value]) : Observable.empty()
```

So, with that said, I recommend you try `concatMap` instead of `switchMap`:

```
subscribeLengthCalculator() {
    this.subscriptions.add(
        this.selectedEntry$
            .concatMap((entry) => {
                return entry ? this.checkService.calculateLinesLength([entry.value]) : Observable.empty();
            }).subscribe(([calculation: CalculationObject]) => {
                    console.log(calculation);
                    this.calculation = calculation;
             })
    );
}
```

but as a matter of fact, I love pipeline operators, so the answer will be:

```
import { concatMap } from 'rxjs/observable/concatMap';

subscribeLengthCalculator() {
        this.subscriptions.add(
            this.selectedEntry$
                .pipe(
                    concatMap((entry) => {
                        return entry ? this.checkService.calculateLinesLength([entry.value]) : Observable.empty();
                    })
                ).subscribe(([calculation: CalculationObject]) => {
                    console.log(calculation);
                    this.calculation = calculation;
                })
        );
    }
```