# Sharing same Observable from a Service in Pages/Components

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, observable

I'm trying to subscribe the same `Observable` multiple times but it doesn't work. I've got a Provider that gives me the `Observable` from `AngularFirestore` object. This is my provider:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyProvider {
  private myObservable: Observable<any>;
  constructor(private aFs: AngularFirestore) {
    //retriving some data and putting in myObservable
  }

  getObservable() {
    return this.myObservable;
  }
}
```

In my `myPage.ts` I do:

```
this.mySubscription = this.myProvider.getObservable().subscribe(value => {
  //something that works
});
```

In another component I do the same but it doesn't give me anything. How I can share an `Observable` from a service or a provider? I've tried to `unsubscribe()` it and it works when i pop from my page to the component, when I call the `unsubscribe()` on the component and then I navigate to my page, the `subscribe()` doesn't work.

To `unsubscribe()` in my page I do:

```
ionViewWillLeave() {
  this.mySubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

To `unsubscribe()` in my component, before I navigate to my page, I do:

```
myEvent() {
  this.mySubscription.unsubscribe();
  this.navCtrl.push(MyPage);
}
```

When I pop from MyPage the `unsubscribe()` seems to work properly because I can see `myObservable` data in my component. When I try to navigate from my component to `MyPage` the `unsubscribe()` seems to doesn't work because I can see nothing. I also tried with debugging but I can't see nothing into the `subscribe()` in the second case.

I import my provider in the `app.module.ts` under `providers` and then I import it in my pages:

MyPage.ts

```
import { MyProvider } from ..;
```

The constructor (MyPage.ts):

```
constructor(private myProvider: MyProvider) {..}
```

And in my component:

MyComponent.ts

```
import { MyProvider } from ..;
```

The constructor (Home.ts)

```
constructor(private myProvider: MyProvider) {..}
```

I clarify that `MyComponent` isn't used in `MyPage`! I use it in the `Home` and then I use it to push to `MyPage`. I'm doing this because I want to show simple data in `MyComponent` and then I want to push to `MyPage` that contains the data details.

Easily I want to share the same Observable retrived from a service on a component  and on a page, and I want to `subscribe()` it on both. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you certain that the provider is provided as a Singleton?

Comment: No, I also thought that, but I can't understand how I can make it singleton. I'm using typescript and it's the first time I'm trying a Provider.

Comment: Can you show where you provide/import the Provider?

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: Share your app.module.ts.

Comment: I've declared it only in the providers into `app.module.ts`, in my page and in my component I only use it in the constructor and import it, not imported in `@Component({...providers: //something})`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your objective is to multicast the data use RXJS's `Subject` or `BehaviorSubject`
`Subject`  acts as a bridge/proxy between the source `Observable` and many `observers`, making it possible for multiple `observers` to share the same `Observable` execution.
This recommended way of exposing Subjects are using the `asObservable()` operator.

```
@Injectable()
export class MyProvider {
  private myObservable=new Subject<any>();
  CurrentData = this.myObservable.asObservable();
  constructor(private aFs: AngularFirestore) {
    //your logic
      this.myObservable.next(value);//push data into observable
  }


}
```

**Page.ts**

```
this.mySubscription = this.myProvider.CurrentData.subscribe(value => {
      //something that works
    });
```

**Using Behavior Subject**

```
 @Injectable()
    export class MyProvider {
      private myObservable=new BehaviorSubject<any>('');
      CurrentData = this.myObservable.asObservable();
      constructor(private aFs: AngularFirestore) {

      }

     getData(myParam): void { 
       someasynccall.pipe(map(),filter()).
          subscribe(value=>this.myObservable.next(value))


    }
```

**Page.ts**

```
this.myProvider.getData(param);
this.mySubscription = this.myProvider.CurrentData.subscribe(value => {
      //something that works
    });
```

**[`Subject vs BehaviorSubject`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348463/what-is-the-difference-between-subject-and-behaviorsubject)**

**[`LiveDemo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zbovjg)**

Comment: How I can do if i want to make a call with parameters? I want currentData that depends on parameter I pass to the Provider. Like  `getData(myParam): Observable<any> { //dothings like filter or map; myObservable.subscribe(value => { this.currentData.next(value) }); return this.currentData.asObservable(); }`

Comment: are you making an `Http` call?

Comment: I don't understand your requirement fully but you cannot return a value from `subscribe` callback you are working with async programming you need to wait until your subscription is resolved and then take appropriate action

Comment: I have updated my code and provided a wroking stackblitz have a look

Comment: Your code is right, i was thinking something like that, but the behaviour I aspected is different. The behaviorSubject 'pass' me a different Observable every time and with the next method I add observables, so every time I add something I must add .next([]) before because I can visualize the old values in the new call.