# How to notify dump component when a http call is failed?

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-event-emitter

Currently I have a smart component `products.component.ts` and one dump component `products-create.component.ts`. The dump component emits an event to the smart component when the user submits on create button.

The `products.component.ts` makes a `http` call to save the product in the server. Now what i need to know is, how to notify the dump component that the service call is succeeded or failed? The dump component should show the error when failure and navigate to list component while success.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could use RXJS'S `Subejct` or `BehaviorSubject` to multicast the data.
[`Example`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50915201/5695162)

Better approach Would be to  share a single `http` request for multiple observers using [`shareReplay`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/sharereplay.html) operator and take action accordingly.
You must be aware of the fact that `http` returns a cold observable and
When a cold `observable` has multiple `subscribers`, the whole data stream is re-emitted for each `subscriber`. Each subscriber becomes independent and gets its own stream of data

To  Avoid Duplication of HTTP Requests `shareReplay` Operator is used.

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
    import {shareReplay,tap}from 'rxjs/operators';
    @Injectable()
    export class ShareService {

    public response$:Observable<any>;
    constructor(private httpc:HttpClient)
    {
      this.sendRequest();
    }
    public sendRequest()
    {

     this.response$= this.httpc.get('url').
        pipe(tap(res=>{console.log('called');return res;}),shareReplay(1))

    }
    fetchData()
    {

    return this.response$;
    }
    }
```

**products.component.ts:**

```
     constructor(service:ShareService)
      {

         service.fetchData().subscribe(result=>{
         console.log(result);

        })
```

**products-create.component.ts:**

```
     constructor(service:ShareService)
      {

         service.fetchData().subscribe(result=>{

         console.log(result);this.route.navigate(['listcomp'])

        }
        error=>{your logic}
         )
```

[`Further Reading`](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-http/)

Comment: Hi, If the provided answer has solved your question please consider accepting it

Answer (score 0):

You can do it inside the ngOnChanges method from the OnChanges interface:

basically, you need to pass a property from the parent component to the child component, named 'responseState', if this property changed from the parent component, ngOnChanges method is triggered, then you check the property value.

child.component.ts:

```
@Component({...})
export class ChildComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() responseState: boolean;

  // this method is triggered when the Input properties changed.
  ngOnChanges() {
     if(responseState) {
            // successful request
     }else {
           // failed request
     }
  }
}
```

in the parent component:

```
@Component({...})
export class ParentComponent {
   responseState = undefined;

   doRequest() {
       /**
        * If the request is failed,
        * set 'this.responseState = false'
        * 
        * if the request is successful
        * set 'this.responseState = true'
        */
   }
}
```

parent template:

```
...
<child-component
   [responseState]='responseState'
> </child-component>
...
```