# Angular 6 RxJs: Trying to make an obj as observable to be use in other components

Tags: angular, rxjs6, subject-observer

## Service

```
mode: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    this.setMode({ // defaults
        admin: this.admins.includes(localStorage.getItem("email")),
        edit: false,
        dev: false
    });
}

getMode() {
    return this.mode.asObservable();
}

setMode(value) {
    this.mode.next(value);
}
```

### Component

```
constructor(private bcAuthService: BcAuthService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.bcAuthService.getMode().subscribe(mode => {
    console.log('mode: ', mode); // never logs or prints in the template
    this.mode = mode;
  });
}
editToggle(e) {
  this.mode.edit = e.target.checked; // err: cant edit `mode` because it never set.
  this.bcAuthService.mode.next(this.mode);
}
```

### Question

I am trying to set up an Observable to be read and wrote from many components. As seen above; I set up the observable in my service but my component `getMode()` doesnt work. Any ideas why?

Comment: You may need to use `ReplaySubject` instead

Comment: How are you injecting the service into your components?

Comment: the service works its the getMode that is not working. I cant understand why

Comment: you're updating the `Subject` before you subscribe it. You've to switch it's type to `ReplaySubject` or `BehaviorSubject` to achieve the desired effect. The subjects have different behavior

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your architecture is correct, but I think you should use `BehaivourSubject` instead of `Subject`

try this:

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
```

**Service**

```
mode: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

    constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
        this.setMode({ // defaults
            admin: this.admins.includes(localStorage.getItem("email")),
            edit: false,
            dev: false
        });
    }

    getMode() {
        return this.mode.asObservable();
    }

    setMode(value) {
        this.mode.next(value);
    }
```

**BehaviorSubject vs Subject**

[What is the difference between Subject and BehaviorSubject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348463/what-is-the-difference-between-subject-and-behaviorsubject)

Comment: `mode: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>();` gets an error `Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.`

Comment: sorry, the constructor requires an argument but you can pass null, it is fixed in my answer now

Comment: this works. I dont know why though. Would be nice to see an explanation for when to use `Subject` and `BehaviorSubject`... Either way thank you!

Comment: you can read more about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348463/what-is-the-difference-between-subject-and-behaviorsubject

Comment: The summary is: `Subject` only notify the subscribers and `BehaviorSubject` notify and send the value

Answer (score 0):

```
editToggle(e) {
this.mode.edit = e.target.checked; // err: cant edit `mode` because it 
// never set.
this.bcAuthService.setMode(e.target.checked);
}
```

I guess this should work

I did something similar by modifying a fork [Component Interaction](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1k1lt7).