# Several Observables in a parent component Vs One Observable in each child component

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Let's imagine we have two models `Player` and `World` and we want to display a player's information with its world's information within a common view. We get those information through two Observables `playerObservable` and `worldObvservable`. We define `PlayerComponent` (parent), `PlayerInformationComponent`(child) and `WorldInformationComponent`(child).

I'm wondering which solution is the most efficient :

- In `PlayerComponent`, I load both player and world information in parallel :

  ```
  // player.component.ts
  forkJoin([playerObservable, worldObservable])
      .subscribe(([player, world]) => {
          this.player = player;
          this.world = world;
      });
  ```

  and provide each information to the corresponding component :

  ```
  // player.component.html
  <app-player [player]="player"></app-player>
  <app-world [world]="world"></app-world>
  ```

  having a `ngIf` in each child component :

  ```
  // player-information.component.html
  <div *ngIf="player">...</div>

  // world-information.component.html
  <div *ngIf="world">...</div>
  ```

  And an `@Input` in each :

  ```
  // player-information.component.ts
  @Input() public player: Player;

  // world-information.component.ts
  @Input() public world: World;
  ```
- Each child component load its own information :

  ```
  // player-information.component.ts
  playerObservable.subscribe((player) => { this.player = player; });

  // world-information.component.ts
  worldObservable.subscribe((world) => { this.world = world; });
  ```

  And :

  ```
  // player.component.html
  <app-player></app-player>
  <app-world></app-world>
  ```

Comment: I don't know that one is more efficient than the other. There are different reasons why you might want to use either. Do you want to block the whole ui until both load? Does one take a lot longer than the other to load and you only want to block part of the ui? etc. At the end of the day, you are loading both it seems so I wouldn't imagine one is more efficient than the other.

Comment: are these `Observables` returned by `http` call?

Comment: @peinearydevelopment Thank you for your answer ! So it needs to be adapted to the project and the behavior wanted

Comment: @Vikas Yes, they are !

Answer (score 1):

There is no much difference for your case, I just suggest to decide depending on in which components you need these data, if in parent and children - get in parent and share with child components, if only in child components - you can get data separately right in these children.

BUT

If you have many child components, for example, you repeat something dynamically via `*ngFor`, I strongly recommend to get the data in parent component and share with children. Otherwise, you will have, for example 50 components and 50 subscriptions, and it will slow down the app very much.

Answer (score 1):

Use `services` to share data
Angular distinguishes components from services in order to increase modularity and reusability.
**[`and It's Good Practice to Delegate complex component logic to services`](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#delegate-complex-component-logic-to-services)**

> From **Angular Style Guide**
>  Do limit logic in a component to only
>   that required for the view. All other logic should be delegated to
>   services.
>
> Do move reusable logic to services and keep components simple and
>   focused on their intended purpose.
>
> Why? Logic may be reused by multiple components when placed within a
>   service and exposed via a function.
>
> Why? Logic in a service can more easily be isolated in a unit test,
>   while the calling logic in the component can be easily mocked.
>
> Why? Removes dependencies and hides implementation details from the
>   component.
>
> Why? Keeps the component slim, trim, and focused.

If your objective is to multicast the data use RXJS's `Subject` or `BehaviorSubject`
`Subject`  acts as a bridge/proxy between the source `Observable` and many `observers`, making it possible for multiple `observers` to share the same `Observable` execution.

Advantages of `BehaviorSubject` over `Subject`

1. It will always return the current value on subscription - there is no need to call 
   `onnext().`
2. It has a `getValue()` function to extract the last value as raw data.
3. It ensures that the component always receives the most recent data.
4. you can get an observable from behavior subject using the `asobservable()` 
        method on `BehaviorSubject`.
5. [`Subject vs BehaviorSubject`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348463/what-is-the-difference-between-subject-and-behaviorsubject)

**Service**

```
 private firstResponse=new BehaviorSubject<any>('');
     private secondResponse=new BehaviorSubject<any>('');
          CurrentDatafirst = this.firstResponse.asObservable();
          CurrentDatasecond = this.secondResponse.asObservable();
    getdata(){
       forkJoin([playerObservable, worldObservable])
    .subscribe(([player, world]) => {

    this.firstResponse.next(player),
    this.secondResponse.next(world)
  })
    });
   }
```

**Component1:**

```
ngOnInit()
{
  this.service.CurrentDatafirst.subscribe(//value=>your logic);
  this.service.CurrentDatasecond.subscribe(//value=>your logic)

}
```

**Component2:**

```
 ngOnInit()
    {
      this.service.CurrentDatafirst.subscribe(//value=>your logic);
      this.service.CurrentDatasecond.subscribe(//value=>your logic)

    }
```

**[`RxJS Subjects for human beings`](https://netbasal.com/rxjs-subjects-for-human-beings-7807818d4e4d)**

**[`BehaviorSubject in Angular`](https://netbasal.com/angular-2-persist-your-login-status-with-behaviorsubject-45da9ec43243)**
**[`Live Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-forkjoin-behaviorsub)**

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

you could also share a single `http` request for multiple observers using [`shareReplay`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/sharereplay.html) operator and take action accordingly.
You must be aware of the fact that `http` returns a cold observable and
When a cold `observable` has multiple `subscribers`, the whole data stream is re-emitted for each `subscriber`. Each subscriber becomes independent and gets its own stream of data

To  Avoid Duplication of HTTP Requests `shareReplay` Operator is used.
**Service**

```
 public response$:Observable<any>
    getdata(){
               forkJoin([playerObservable, worldObservable]).pipe(sharReplay(1));
            }

   fetchdata()
           {
              this.response$;
            }
```

Component1:

```
 ngOnInit()
    {
      this.service.fetchdata().subscribe(//value=>your logic);


    }
```

Component2:

```
    ngOnInit()
    {
      this.service.fetchdata().subscribe(//value=>your logic);


    }
```

**[`Live Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-forkjoin-ex)**

Comment: Sorry, I haven't been enough precise. My `Observables` are provided by Services returning `http` calls.
Your explanation on `Observables` are anyhow interesting. I don't really understand why there is a `subscribe` within the service but I'm really unfamiliar with `Subject` and `BehaviorSubject` as I am still discovering `Observables` _(and have undoubtedly many things to discover)_.
Thank you for your presentation of `shareReplay` which appears to be really useful !

Comment: I finally understood the purpose of `Subject` and `BehaviorSubject`. Those pages help : [`Subject`](https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/subjects/subject/index.html) and [`BehaviorSubject`](https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/subjects/behavior_subject/index.html)

Comment: I have updated my question go through the links to get a clearer picture