# Unable to bind the data while subscribe using subject in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

Actually unable to find how to bind the data using angular 6 while if share the data with sibling components using subject concept. I separated routing modules for dashboard

In dashboard have to show respective data on click in other component, but it displays in console unable to bind the data in view oninit.

It works in Behaviour subject but not in subject how?

Anyone please help me to learn the concept behind this.

Giving the github path for your reference

https://github.com/uiforchange/AngularComponentLazyLoading.git

Comment: can you prepare a minimal working example in stackblitz? you have several components/services and would be easy to isolate the problem

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `BehaviorSubject` and `Subject` is that the `BehaviorSubject` holds an value and immediately emits this value on subscription.
A `Subject` on the other hand does **not** hold a value on subscription, which is why you are unable to bind to the data immediately.

You are able to bind to the data you get by changing to `BehaviorSubject` or by emitting a new value **after** subscription.

([Taken from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348463/what-is-the-difference-between-subject-and-behaviorsubject))

Comment: But binding happens for the subject also mentioned in the url https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-subject-and-behaviorsubject?file=app%2Fmyservice.ts

Comment: You are right, but it only happens if the value changed **after** the subscription.

Comment: the value changed after the subscription only, but not binds

Comment: That is correct, but on the subscription there was no value emitted.

Comment: In this example you do **not** subscribe on click. You just emit a new value. The subscription happen before.