# Updating the time of a Date subject

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, service

Is there a way in which I can update say the time of a Subject within my service?

I am thinking of abstracting the following function into a service:

```
date: Date;

setTime(hours: number, mins: number, secs: number): void {
    this.date.setHours(hours);
    this.date.setMinutes(mins);
    this.date.setSeconds(secs);
  }
```

**service example**

```
date: Subject<Date>;

  constructor() {
    this.date = new Subject();
  }

  setDate(hrs: number, mins: number, secs: number): Observable<Date> {
    const tempDate = this.date;
    // tempDate.set - Cannot do .setXXX here since it is a Subject and not a Date
    this.date.next
  }
```

[**stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/off-time-edit)

Comment: isnt the problem that you cant use `tempDate.set()` because it is a `const` and not a `let` declaration?

Comment: this lib might be help you for time related operations, https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns

Comment: @TeunvanderWijst The problem here is that I can't get any `setXXX` functions to appear on the `tempDate`, no matter if it is `let` or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just create a new date, that copies the date part of the current date, and uses time parameters. and then push the tempDate to the subject.

something like this:

```
setDate(hrs: number, mins: number, secs: number): Observable<Date> {
   let tempDate = this.date.getValue(); //gets the value of the subject, not the actual subject
   tempDate.setHours(hours);
   tempDate.setMinutes(mins);
   tempDate.setSeconds(secs);
   this.date.next(tempDate);
}
```

Comment: `'getValue' does not exist on type 'Subject<Date>` :-(

Comment: is it possible to change `Subject<Date>` to `BehaviourSubject<Date>` ? explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348463/what-is-the-difference-between-subject-and-behaviorsubject

Comment: Hmm. It accepts the BehaviorSubject definition, but I still cann't get to the `.setXXX` functions. I have saved as a new stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/off-time-edit-behaviorsubject

Comment: @physicsboy I've updated your stackblitz. It's working now, the problem is you dit `const tempDate = this.date` and you should've done `const tempDate = this.date.getValue()` once i did that i was abe to access `.setXXX` functions. have a look