# How to create an http observable that makes dynamic requests

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an observable that makes dynamic requests.

For example,

```
getFlowers(params?: any): Obeservable<Flower[]> {
  return this.http.get<Flower[]>(
    `http://flowers.com/flowers`, { params }
  )
}
```

Now, the above function returns new `http` observable each function call. I would like to somehow achieve returning the same observable instance (despite making different http calls) such that I can use `switchMap` to cancel previous simultaneous requests.

I have an idea that I should create an Observable property (singleton), but I fail to realize how to utilize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, the above function returns new http observable each function call??

This is actually the normal behavior of the `HTTP` observables as they are Cold.
When a cold `observable` has multiple `subscribers`, the whole data stream is re-emitted for each `subscriber`. Each subscriber becomes independent and gets its own stream of data
**Approach:1**
To  Avoid Duplication of HTTP Requests you can use [`shareReplay`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/sharereplay.html) operator.

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { shareReplay, tap } from "rxjs/operators";
@Injectable()
export class ShareService {
  public response$: Observable<any>;
  constructor(private httpc: HttpClient) {
    this.sendRequest();
  }
  public sendRequest() {
    this.response$ = this.httpc.get("url").pipe(
      tap(res => {
        console.log("called");
        return res;
      }),
      shareReplay(1)
    );
  }
  fetchData() {
    return this.response$;
  }
}
```

**component1:**

```
constructor(service: ShareService) {
    service.fetchData().subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result);
    });
  }
```

**component2:**

```
   constructor(service: ShareService) {
    service.fetchData().subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result);
    });
  }
```

[`Further Reading`](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-http/)
**[`Live Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-isfka6)**
**Approach:2**
If your objective is to multicast the data use RXJS's `Subject` or `BehaviorSubject`
`Subject`  acts as a bridge/proxy between the source `Observable` and many `observers`, making it possible for multiple `observers` to share the same `Observable` execution.
This recommended way of exposing Subjects are using the `asObservable()` operator.

```
@Injectable()
export class MyProvider {
  private myObservable=new Subject<any>();
  CurrentData = this.myObservable.asObservable();
  constructor(private aFs: AngularFirestore) {
    //your logic
      this.myObservable.next(value);//push data into observable
  }


}
```

**Page.ts**

```
this.mySubscription = this.myProvider.CurrentData.subscribe(value => {
      //something that works
    });
```

**Using Behavior Subject**

```
@Injectable()
export class MyProvider {
  private myObservable = new BehaviorSubject<any>("");
  CurrentData = this.myObservable.asObservable();
  constructor(private aFs: AngularFirestore) {}

  getData(myParam): void {
    someasynccall
      .pipe(
        map(),
        filter()
      )
      .subscribe(value => this.myObservable.next(value));
  }
}
```

**Page.ts**

```
this.myProvider.getData(param);
this.mySubscription = this.myProvider.CurrentData.subscribe(value => {
      //something that works
    });
```

**[`Subject vs BehaviorSubject`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348463/what-is-the-difference-between-subject-and-behaviorsubject)**

**[`LiveDemo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zbovjg)**

Comment: Thanks you, especially for providing multiple approaches