# How do I update the state of buttons in tabs in ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am building an app using the tabbed template in Ionic. It has 4 buttons. . 
[image: Fig 1]

When the user is logged out, the 4th button should take them to the login/registration page as above.

[image: Fig 2]

When they are logged in, it should show a logout button as shown above.

Below is my code in `tabs.html` showing my tabs:

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Home" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Search" tabIcon="search"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="List Providers" tabIcon="list"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab4Root" tabTitle="Login/Register" tabIcon="finger-print" *ngIf="loggedIn"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab tabTitle="Logout" tabIcon="exit" (click)="logout()" *ngIf="!loggedIn"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

When I test out this arrangement by manually setting the value of the boolean variable `loggedIn` in `tabs.ts`, it works as expected.

What I want is for the tabs to switch automatically, depending on whether or not the user is logged in. When a user successfully logs in, I am setting a value `loggedIn` in local storage to true. I then have the code below in my `tabs.ts` which should toggle the login/logout buttons:

```
loggedIn: boolean = false;

  ionViewWillEnter(): void {

    if (localStorage.getItem('loggedIn') == 'true') {
      this.loggedIn = true;
      console.log("we are logged in!");
    } else {
      this.loggedIn = false;
      console.log("we are logged out");
    }
  }
```

The problem however, is that though the value of the variable loggedIn is being set and changed correctly, the view in `tabs.html` is not updating to then show the logout button, it still shows the login/register button. How can i get the tab to refresh each time it a button is clicked? I have tried adding code to the `ionViewWillEnter()` function but it did not work. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

My system:

```
$ ionic info

Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.0.3 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.0.0

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
   NodeJS            : v8.10.0 (/usr/bin/node)
   npm               : 3.5.2
   OS                : Linux 4.15

Environment:

   ANDROID_HOME : /home/user/Android/Sdk
```

Comment: So when you hit this page you are seeing `we are logged in!` in the console?

Comment: @BRass yes. Also the value of loggedIn is true.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using a local event of tabs ionViewWillEnter(), so it only will get the value once, i suggest you to create a external provider and use that provider var to set the state of your tabs, changing the value of the var in the provider when you change your state to loggedIn/Off.

```
import { GlobalProvider } from "../../providers/globals"
constructor(        
    public global: GlobalProvider,
){
    if(!this.global.loggedIn)this.global.loggedIn=false;
}
```

in the provider

```
@Injectable()
export class GlobalProvider {
    public loggedIn = false;
}
```

in the html

```
<ion-tabs>
   <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Home" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
   <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Search" tabIcon="search"></ion-tab>
   <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="List Providers" tabIcon="list"></ion-tab>
   <ion-tab [root]="tab4Root" tabTitle="Login/Register" tabIcon="finger-print" *ngIf="global.loggedIn"></ion-tab>
   <ion-tab tabTitle="Logout" tabIcon="exit" (click)="logout()" *ngIf="!global.loggedIn"> 
</ion-tab>
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the best way to implement this, is to create a `Subject<boolean>` or `BehaviourSubject<boolean>` (this is the difference between them https://stackoverflow.com/a/43351340/7200009). Do you have an AuthService? If so, you can create a subject variable and subscribe to it in your tabspage. 
Something like this:

AuthService.ts

```
  loggedInChanged: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  login(){
    // Your Login logic.
    this.loggedInChanged.next(true);
  }

  logout(){
    // Your Logout logic.
    this.loggedInChanged.next(false);
  }
```

TabsPage.ts

```
  loggedIn: boolean;
  loggedInChangedSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService){}

  ionViewDidLoad(){
    this.loggedInChangedSubscription = this.authService.loggedInChanged.subscribe(loggedIn => {
      this.loggedIn = loggedIn;
    })
  }

  ionViewWillUnload() {
    this.loggedInChangedSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an app with the same behavior that you need what I did was use https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/

you can generate the event from the close session button and receive the event from the tabs.ts