# How to show Template driven form's data to another component after submit in Angular?

Tags: angular

Hi I have a template driven form like Url : https://angular-template-driven-feedbackform.stackblitz.io/ and need to pass data from this form component to another component like usercomponent even this form data coming in console please give me appropriate solution with reason..Thanks

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to share data between components is using a service according to your scenario you can pass values to the service when the user clicks on signup and use those data in another component by subscribing to that service.
Your can use  Behavior-subject or subject to find more information please follow the link on angular guide.
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

To know what is  Behavior-subject and subject please follow
[What is the difference between Subject and BehaviorSubject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348463/what-is-the-difference-between-subject-and-behaviorsubject)

hope this helps!

Comment: Yes it is ok but i need something that is working example if you provide me on stackblitz ...thanks

Comment: ok follow this if you use behavior-subject https://stackblitz.com/edit/best-example-of-passing-data-through-an-object-using-a-service or  if you use subject https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular2-communicating-between-components

Comment: Hi Umesh I implement all in my code but after submit how to route to another page where I have to show message after function call I stuck there can you please give me any solution?

Comment: Use navigate or navigatebyurl methods  like this gotoHeroes() {
  this.router.navigate(['/heroes']);
}

Comment: I set up routing and redirect to a feedback component but from home to component message did not display I have added here https://angular2-communicating-between-components-u2mkue.stackblitz.io/ can you pls see...

Comment: Ok you have to use behavior-subject now its working fine plez follow this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular2-communicating-between-components-vp8m84?file=app%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.ts