# Issue Regarding BehaviorSubject Observable

Tags: angular6

I am trying to Sync the data from REST API to my UI. but when i fetch the record from Rest API and transforms it,it gives an error of undefined:-
 I am attaching my code:-

```
 private datalist: Data[];
  private dataUpdated = new Subject<Data[]>();


  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { 



  }
  getData()
{
  this.http.get<{datalist:any}>("http://myserever/posts")
  .pipe(map((dummydata)=>{
    return dummydata.datalist.map(da=>{
      return {
        Status:da.status
      };
    })

  }))
    .subscribe(data=>{
    this.datalist=data
    console.log("The data is",data);
    this.dataUpdated.next([...this.datalist]);
     })
}
```

Actual Results:-
On pipe Operator it is giving me undefined Error, Here is my Error stack:-

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at MapSubscriber.eval [as project] (get-dummy-data.service.ts:25)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:79)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:95)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:85)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:95)
    at FilterSubscriber._next (filter.js:90)
    at FilterSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:95)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (mergeMap.js:151)
    at InnerSubscriber._next (InnerSubscriber.js:25)
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:95)
```

How i can solve the above probelm
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are not using a BehaviorSubject but a Subject (the difference matter, the behavior subject has a value at initialization, the Subject hasn't).

This post resume the difference [What is the difference between Subject and BehaviorSubject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348463/what-is-the-difference-between-subject-and-behaviorsubject)

It will depends of your needs to switch for a real behavior subject.

The error, `"Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"` could be due to your `dummydata` result that does not contains a datalist property (check casing, spelling ?)

The first map will just take the result of the request (`dummydata`), then the second will try to iterate on `dummydata.datalist` property (is it an array, an object?).

So you could check first if the `dummydata.datalist` property is not undefined, and that it is an iterable thing.

You could modify your code to be like this:

```
    getData(){
        this.http.get<{datalist:any}>("http://myserever/posts").pipe(
            map(dummydata => dummydata.datalist.map(da => {
                return {
                    Status: da.status
                }
            })),
            // Catch it here
            catchError(error => of([{Status: 'Fail'}]))
        ).subscribe(
            data => {
                this.datalist=data
                console.log("The data is",data);
                this.dataUpdated.next([...this.datalist]);
            },
            // Or catch it here
            err => {
                //Do your error handling
            },
            () => // Do something in any case
        )
    }
```

Hope this can help you.