# passing data from one component to another via Subject

Tags: angular

I am trying to pass data from updateproducts.component.ts to `updatecardproducts.component.ts` via Subject using `.pipe(take(1))`

The issue I am facing is that when I click on edit button of parent component(it justs navigates me to the update products component) it takes me to the update products component but in console I do not see anything for the first time but then again if I click I get the result and then after it everything works fine, the problem exists for only the first time I click on edit button . Below is the code

**updateproducts.component.ts**

```
export class UpdateproductsComponent implements OnInit {
recipeform:FormGroup
id:number
product
editmode=false

constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute,private 
router:Router,private prservice:Productservice) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.route.params.subscribe(
  (params)=>{
  this.id=+params['id']
  if(params['id']!=null){
    this.editmode=true
  }
  this.initform()



    })
}


private initform(){
let title=''
let price=''
let select=''
let imageurl=''
if(this.editmode){
   const product=this.prservice.getproductbyid(this.id)



  title=product.title
  price=product.price
  select=product.select
  imageurl=product.imageurl

  this.prservice.updatedproduct.next(product)
  //this is the values i am trying to pass 


}
this.recipeform=new FormGroup({
  'title':new FormControl(title,Validators.required),
  'price':new FormControl(price,Validators.required),
  'select':new FormControl(select,Validators.required),
  'imageurl':new FormControl(imageurl,Validators.required)
})
}

}
```

**products.service.ts**

```
import { Subject } from "rxjs";

 export class Productservice{
updatedproduct=new Subject<any>()
card=new Subject<any>()
cards=[]

addtocards(value){
    this.cards.push(value)
    // console.log(this.cards)
    // console.log(this.cards[0])
}
getallproducts(){
    return this.cards
}

getproductbyid(id){
    // console.log(this.cards[id])
    return this.cards[id]
}

updateproduct(id,product){
   return  this.cards[id]=product
    // this.updatedproduct.next(this.cards.slice())
}

}
```

**updateproducts.component.ts**

```
export class UpdatecardproductsComponent implements OnInit {
subscription:Subscription
carddetails
constructor(private prservice:Productservice) { }

ngOnInit() {

this.subscription=this.prservice.updatedproduct.pipe(take(1))
.subscribe(
  (value)=>{
this.carddetails=value
 console.log(this.carddetails)
  }
)

}

}
```

so first when this component is rendered I do not see anything(this.carddetails) in the console but after that from second time onwards everything works fine and gets displayed in the console

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subject is not working when route navigating from one component to another component in Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54633820/subject-is-not-working-when-route-navigating-from-one-component-to-another-compo)

Comment: Use `BehaviorSubject` or `ReplaySubject` instead.

Comment: @AmitChigadani thnks dude it worked !

Comment: Great, you could upvote the answer that is linked. Because its almost similar. No point in adding the same answer again.

Comment: @AmitChigadani ya i upvoted but can u pls tell me one more thing after receiving the res i console log it and i see the results but i failed to render it in the html component

Comment: @AmitChigadani i tried it like this {{res?.title}}

Comment: Can you please create another question, because that is out of context here and lets not mess the things.

Comment: @AmitChigadani okayyy