# Subject not triggering when being called from parent component in ngOnInit

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular7, ngoninit

I'm using Rxjs and Angular 7. I have a parent component and a child component. I have a method to invoke a `Subject` on my child component:

```
updateSubject(text: string) {
  this.subject$.next(text);
}
```

And I'm calling this from my parent component in `ngOnInit` using `ViewChild`:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.childComponent.updateSubject('New Text');
}
```

But the `subscribe` for `this.subject$` is never triggered if I am calling it from `ngOnInit` in the parent component. If I call the method using a button from either parent or child, the the `subscribe` triggers fine. What am I doing wrong?

See the StackBlitz demonstration [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v6c91m).

Comment: You probably subscribe after you call `updateSubject` from `ngOnInit()`. Hard to tell unless you share all the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `subscribe()` in the child is being called **after** the parent is initialized. Angular initializes components in the same order as the DOM so the parent component is initialized first, and then the child is initialized.

A `Subject()` throws away emitted values if nothing is subscribed, and since the child is subscribing late it doesn't receive the value.

You can use a [BehaviorSubject()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/subjects/behaviorsubject.html) or a [ReplaySubject()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/subjects/replaysubject.html) depending if you need an initial value or not.

Comment: Sometimes I do need an initial value, other times I don't. Wouldn't you say it would be better to use the `afterViewInit` lifecycle hook to call the method in the child component instead?

Comment: @Viqas `afterViewInit` requires a developer to know about this *special* requirement. How would they know? Add documentation, or an example. If they don't use `afterViewInit` is it okay for the child to break? For me, it should not matter what the parent does.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `AfterViewInit` lifecycle hook. Your child component hasn't been rendered yet when `OnInit` is called.

So this will work:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
 this.childComponent.updateSubject('View initialized');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use BehaviorSubject instead of Subject

```
subject$: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);
```

Follow this question to understand difference between Subject and BehaviorSubject

[Difference between Subject and BehaviorSubject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348463/what-is-the-difference-between-subject-and-behaviorsubject)