# Why an Observable variable is not updating in real-time in Angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'm new in Angular and I'm trying to transfer the data between 2 siblings in real-time:

This is my service:

**message-transfer-service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Products } from './products';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import "rxjs/add/observable/of";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})


export class MessageTransferService {

  private products = new Products();

  getProducts() : Observable<Products> {
    if (this.products)
      return Observable.of(this.products);
  }

  setProducts(product: Products) {
    this.products = product;
  }

  constructor() { }
}
```

This is my first sibling:

**products-list.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { MessageTransferService } from '../message-transfer.service';
import { Products } from '../products';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-products-list',
  templateUrl: './products-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./products-list.component.css']
})
export class ProductsListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private service: MessageTransferService){ }

  product: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.product = { "id": 1, "name": "Cat", "age": 30 };
    this.setProducts();
  }

  setNewProduct() {
    this.product = { "id": 2, "name": "Dog", "age": 30 };
    this.setProducts();    
  }

  setProducts() {
    let d : Products = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.product));
    this.service.setProducts(d);
  }
}
```

**product-list.component.html**

```
<p>products-list works!</p>
<button (click)="setNewProduct()">Set new book</button>
```

This is my second sibling:

**product-details.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MessageTransferService } from '../message-transfer.service';
import { Products } from '../products';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-details',
  templateUrl: './product-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-details.component.css']
})
export class ProductDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  product: Observable<Products>;

  constructor(private service: MessageTransferService){

   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getProducts();
  }

  getProducts() {
    this.product = this.service.getProducts();
    console.log(this.product);
  }
}
```

**product-details.component.html**

```
<p>product-details works!</p>

<button (click)="getProducts()">Click</button>

<p>{{product}}</p>
```

If I click on the button, the data is refreshed:

[image: example]

What I'm looking forward to is when I do click on the Set new book, its content should be automatically updated since the values are updated in the service, but until I do click on the button Click it's reflected in the console. Do you have any idea, what should I change? Probably is something in the constructor of product-details, but I'm not sure since I'm quite new in this area. Thanks for any hint.

I'm working with Angular 8 and the latest version of RXJS.

Comment: I don't see an emit anywhere. You give the observable an initial value - but never emit a new one. The Observable does not know if a local variable somewhere was changed.

Comment: Try - `<p>{{product | async}}</p>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `BehaviorSubject`(Thanks @fredrik).

```
export class MessageTransferService {

  private products = new Products();
  products$ = new BehaviorSubject<Products>(this.products)

  setProducts(product: Products) {
    this.products$.next(product)
  }

  constructor() { }
}
```

```
export class ProductDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  product$: this.service.product$;

  constructor(private service: MessageTransferService){

   }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

```html
<p>{{product$ | async}}</p>
```

Comment: This should work - personally I normally prefer to use the BehaviourSubject (because it [holds a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348463/what-is-the-difference-between-subject-and-behaviorsubject), but that's a matter of taste)

Comment: It's working, but I have a question, how can I know when it changed from the ProductDetailsComponent? Because I need to change something from the TS side :/.

Comment: You can subscribe to it `this.service.product$.subscribe(value => { // do something })`.

Comment: Should I add the subscribe in the constructor or ProductDetailsComponent? Or where exactly? Sorry, as I said I'm quite new in this topic :\.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-observable-variable-not-updating-in-real-time)

You can save your list like this with `BehaviorSubject` in your service:

```
export class MessageTransferService {

  private productsSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Products[]>([]);
  public products$ = this.productsSubject.asObservable();

  setProducts(product: Products) {
    const products = this.productsSubject.getValue();
    products.push(product);
    this.productsSubject.next(products);
  }

}
```

And recover it by subscribing :

```
export class ProductDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  products: Products[];

  constructor(private service: MessageTransferService){ }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.products$.subscribe(products => this.products = products)
  }
}
```

`setProducts(product)` of your service thus retrieves the existing list and adds the new product to the list.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning Observable and not subscribing it

```
export class MessageTransferService {

  private products = new Products();
  private productSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Product>(this.products);

  getProducts() : Observable<Products> {
    if (this.products)
        return this.productSubject.asObservable();
  }

  setProducts(product: Products) {
     this.products = product;
     this.productSubject.next(this.products);
  }

  constructor() { }
}
```

and subscribe it in component