# Not able to get Observable value into other modules component using shared services

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-services, shared-module

Please check this GitHub repo https://github.com/nileshzala005/Service-demo

`userService` registered at root level.

I would like to get `getUserLogin` observable value into `SharedModule`'s `UserComponent`. When user clicks on the button **Send value to user component** from the `HomeComponent` that is declared in the `HomeModule`.

`UserService` at the root level:

```
userLogin = new Subject<string>();

  constructor() { }
  sendUserLogin(user: string) {
    console.log("value received at user service ", user);
    this.userLogin.next(user);
  }
  getUserLogin(): Observable<string> {
    return this.userLogin.asObservable();
  }
```

`HomeComponent` in the `HomeModule`:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private userService: UserService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  onClick() {
    console.log("value is send from home component", "Nilesh")
    this.userService.sendUserLogin("Nilesh");
  }

}
```

`UserComponent` in `SharedModule`:

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.getUserLogin().subscribe(res => {
          /// here it should receive but not able to get it
      console.log("user component should get value here ", res);
    });
  }

}
```

[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raKUV.png)

Comment: You're not using your `UserComponent` anywhere in your github example. Your code works if you actually create an instance of your `UserComponent` e.g by adding it to your `app.component.html`. See: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-mz7lqy

Comment: @fridoo Thanks. It's working

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use a BehaviorSubject instead of a Subject to get the value emitted. Check this post for explanation. Syntax is a bit out dated but it still follows the same concept

[What is the difference between Subject and BehaviorSubject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348463/what-is-the-difference-between-subject-and-behaviorsubject)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `BehaviorSubject` instead of `Subject`. It'll send the last value to the subscription even if the subscription was done after the value was emitted.

Could be a problem that you subscribe after the value is emitted.