# angular2 - Not able to get data from subject

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I want to get initialise and get data from service using a subject.
What am I doing wrong?

**HomeComponentComponent.TS**

```
export class HomeComponentComponent implements OnInit {

  public homeSub;
  constructor(
    private subService: SubjectService
  ) { }
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.subService.initialiseSubject(true);
    this.subService.getSubject().subscribe(res => {
      this.homeSub = res;
      console.log(res);
    })
  }

}
```

**HomeComponentComponent.HTML**

```
<p>
{{homeSub}}
</p>
```

**subject.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class SubjectService {

  constructor() { }
  private subTest = new Subject<boolean>();

  initialiseSubject(params: boolean) {
    this.subTest.next(params);
  }
  getSubject() {
    return this.subTest.asObservable();
  }
}
```

I am not getting any output on console or html.
[Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/subjectangular?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/home-component/home-component.component.ts)

Comment: Subjects are "Hot Observables". They emit values regardless of subscribers. You could use a `BehaviorSubject` or a `ReplaySubject`. These specialized subjects propagate values to subscribers who subscribe after the value has been emitted by the subject.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, I changed `Subject` to `BehaviorSubject`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change to `BehaviorSubject`, you will get the emitted value.

```
private subTest = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
```

Please review [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348463/what-is-the-difference-between-subject-and-behaviorsubject) post.

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked. I got just one issue with this.
Do I have to initialise `BehaviorSubject` always?

Comment: As far as I know, the purpose of using `BehaviorSubject` is to have an initial value. I don't think you can create a `BehaviorSubject` object without any initial value.

Comment: If you don't want an initial value, you can use a `ReplaySubject` with a retention of `1`. I.e. `new ReplaySubject<boolean>(1)`