# Sending data to components through services using the subject in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-observable

I have a component that displays a message for a few seconds, my problem is that I can not subscribe to the service and perform the necessary operations, how to do this?

This was a short example, I want to call the message component at all stages of the project, how do I do that?

homeComponent.ts:

```
    export class HomeComponent  {
      constractor(privat _service:IHomeService){}
      getMessage(){
        this._service.get();
      }
    }
```

homeComponent.html:

```
<p (click)="getMessage()">
 show Message 
</p>
```

homeService.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class HomeService {
  openMessage=new Subject<string>();
  get() {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.openMessage.next("test")
    },1000)
  }
}
```

messageComponent.ts:

```
export class MessageComponent  {
  constructor(private _service:HomeService){
    this._service.openMessage.subscribe((res)=>{
      this.name=res;
      this.flag=true;
      setTimeout(()=>{
        this.flag=false;
      },4000)
    })
  }
  name = '';
  flag:boolean=false
}
```

messageComponent.html:

```
<p [ngStyle]="flag?'display:block':'display:none'">
  {{name}}
</p>
```

I think this does not happen because the message component is not loaded
How do I load it in the service?

Comment: Where is the `messageComponent`'s selector included? Something like `<app-message></app-message>`

Comment: I do not want to include it anywhere, I want to load in the service, because it is for the whole project and not a specific part

Comment: Check the difference of a `Subject` and `BehaviourSubject` from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348463/what-is-the-difference-between-subject-and-behaviorsubject).You may need to replace `Subject` with `BehaviourSubject`.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you loading messageComponent?

```
homeComponent.html:
    <p (click)="getMessage()">
     show Message  // if you loading message component here then you should use message component's selector here
    </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't "load" a component in a service, services in Angular store logics, they don't consume components.

If `MessageComponent` is responsibile for displaying the message in the UI then you just need to use it in your template. Assuming its selector is `message-component` you can add it to your `HomeComponent` template:

```
<p (click)="getMessage()">
 <message-component></message-component>
</p>
```

Comment: This was a small example, I use it in many places and I can not do it anywhere in the import, iodine in the service, how to do it?

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear to me what's your issue here. Reusing components is the point of having a component for that specific UI fragment. Again, you can not "load" components in a service. You can dynamically load a component in your UI instead of using a selector in your template, if that's your problem. I suggest you add some more details on what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the Observable var in your service. Here is how you should do it :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class HomeService {
  private openMessage: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
  public $openMessage: Observable<string> = this.openMessage.asObservable();

  public sendMessage(message: string) {
    this.openMessage.next(message);
  }
}
```

And then you will be able to call the `subscribe()` method to the $openMessage variable declared in your class. Here is how to update your `MessageComponent.ts` :

```
export class MessageComponent {
  public name: string = '';
  public flag: boolean = false;

  constructor(private _service:HomeService){
    this._service.$openMessage.subscribe((message)=>{
      this.message = res;
      this.flag = true;
      setTimeout(()=>{
        this.flag=false;
      },4000)
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: `Subject`s are Observables and you can subscribe to them, they expose a `subscribe()` method. What you're doing here is certainly a good practice in order to encapsulate the ability to _emit_ a new value but has nothing to do with the ability to _subscribe_

Comment: No, I tried, but it does not work, because it must be imported first, how can I do this import in the service?