# Get a service callback function response in component

Tags: angular

My component calling a function from service which get data through a sdk.  Sdk get data and response in a callback function. It returns before getting any response of callback function. How can i inform my component that service callback response done?

**Component.ts**

```
async publishSession() {

    let publishCallback = await this.myService.publishStream();
    
  }
```

**Service.ts**

```
callbackResponse;
publishStream(publishCapabilities, mediaConstraints) {
    this.session = session;

    var videoElement = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];

    var publishOptions = {
      publishToken: publishing,
      mediaConstraints: mediaConstraints,
      videoElement: videoElement
    };

    return this.sdk.publishToChannel(publishOptions, this.publisherCallback.bind(this));
  }

publisherCallback(error, response) {
    
      if (error) {
        this.logger.log(error);
      }

 this.callbackResponse = response; // need this response in component once received here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to solve this. One of them is using `Promise` and another one is using observables. Given that the library you are using is based on promises, we can think about it in the following way:

```
publishStream(publishCapabilities, mediaConstraints): Promise<any> {
  this.session = session;

  var videoElement = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];

  var publishOptions = {
    publishToken: publishing,
    mediaConstraints: mediaConstraints,
    videoElement: videoElement
  };


  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.sdk.publishToChannel(publishOptions, (error, response) => {
      if (error) {
        reject(error);
        return;
      }
      resolve(response);
    });
  });
}
```

And now when you call this, you will get the `response` of the `publishToChannel` call.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `Subject` into your service and subscribe in the component to that subject property to get callback response. Update your component and service respectively:

**Component.ts**

```js
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private service: YourService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {

        // here we will subscribe to the new value of a callback response
        this.service
            .callbackResponse
            .subscribe(response => {
                // process your response here...
            });
    }
}
```

**Service.ts**

```js
export class UtilsService {
    callbackResponse = new Subject();

    publishStream(publishCapabilities, mediaConstraints) {
        this.session = session;

        var videoElement = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];

        var publishOptions = {
        publishToken: publishing,
        mediaConstraints: mediaConstraints,
        videoElement: videoElement
        };

        return this.sdk.publishToChannel(publishOptions, this.publisherCallback.bind(this));
    }

    publisherCallback(error, response) {
        
        if (error) {
            this.logger.log(error);
        }

        // this will send a response to the subscription in your component
        this.callbackResponse.next(response);
    }
}
```

Above example should work, but there are couple things to consider

- [`Subject` vs. `BehaviorSubject`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348463/what-is-the-difference-between-subject-and-behaviorsubject)
- any component which will subscribe to `callbackResponse` `Subject` will have access to the response - nothing bad, just something you should be aware of
- it's good to add type, if you know the shape of your response, e.g. `new Subject<T>()` instead of `new Subject()`