# Is there a reason I shouldn't use this extension of RxJS's ReplaySubject?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm new to RxJS. I basically wanted a `BehaviorSubject` that doesn't require an initial value. I created it like this:

```js
class AsyncBehaviorSubject<T> extends ReplaySubject<T> {
  constructor() {
    super(1)
  }
}
```

It seems that this should be part of the library and that my class is unnecessary but I can't find anywhere in the documentation for an observable that provides this behavior. It makes me feel like I'm missing something.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure this is what you want but you could use simply a `Subject`. You instantiate it without an initial value, can have multiple subscribers but doesn't immediately emit a value on subscription...

Comment: @JuanDeLasNieves But does it provide the previous value on subscribe?

Comment: it does not, but if you require the previous value you have the other types of Subjects. I don't quite understand what you try to achieve, so I'll leave this link here to a similar question, although is related to Angular:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348463/what-is-the-difference-between-subject-and-behaviorsubject

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do whatever you want as long as it makes sense and preserves the logic. But if you need `BehaviorSubject`, why to use `ReplaySubject`? Just set initial value to `undefined` or `null`, as in your way:

```
class AsyncBehaviorSubject<T> extends BehaviorSubject<T> {
  constructor() {
    super(undefined);
  }
}
```

Comment: But wouldn't that still push the value `undefined` down the pipe?

Comment: It would, but you if want behavior subject, then you need initial state