# Angular pass some data from main component to component with another route

Tags: angular

I have main component
`home.component.ts`:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.metaService.getMetaCompany()
    .subscribe((response: Json) => {
      let metaCompany = <MetaCompany>response.data;
      this.interactionService.setGlobalMetaCompany(metaCompany);
    });
}
```

`interaction.service.ts`:

```
private globalMetaCompanySource = new Subject<MetaCompany>();
globalMetaCompany$ = this.globalMetaCompanySource.asObservable();
setGlobalMetaCompany(metaCompany: MetaCompany) {
  this.globalMetaCompanySource.next(metaCompany);
}
```

and component where I need to get data
`left-menu-admin.component.ts`:

```
constructor(private interactionService: InteractionService) {
  this.globalMetaCompanySubscription = this.interactionService.globalMetaCompany$.subscribe(
    (metaCompany: MetaCompany) => {
      this.companyName = metaCompany.companyName;
      this.avatarUri = metaCompany.avatarUri;
    });
}
```

So when app starts I got `MetaCompany` data via ajax query into `home.component.ts` and when I go to `/admin` page I don't see method in constructor of `left-menu-admin.component.ts` is executed. When I press F5 on `/admin` page -> page reloads and method in constructor is executed. What am I doing wrong? And how can I pass some data to another page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In interaction.service.ts, your globalMetaCompanySource  is of type Subject<MetaCompany>. But Subject doesn't store value that you assign to it. When you use next() on subject, and then subscribe to it, nothing will happen. If you subscribe first, and then call next() on it, then subscription will evoke its action.

In your case, you can simply use BehaviourSubject instead of Subject. BehaviourSubjects stores the value that you push to it, and when you subscribe to it, it returns last emitted value.

Here you have explanation with examples on BehaviourSubject vs Subject - [What is the difference between Subject and BehaviorSubject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348463/what-is-the-difference-between-subject-and-behaviorsubject)